# "Route to Server Farm" missing in IIS after installing ARR 3.0

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, iis-10

I am trying to configure IIS for a zero-downtime deployment per [this blog](https://www.offerzen.com/blog/zero-downtime-deployments-in-an-iis-world) (green/blue app deployments). I have setup Application Request Routing (3.0) and URL Rewrite, but after setting up the websites and server farm, I see no "Route to Server Farm" option in the Rewrite rules.

[image: Route-to-server-farm]
*This is what I was expecting to find due to the instructions.*

I have completed the following steps on IIS 10 (Windows 10) and IIS 8.5 (Server 2012 R2):

1. Installed Application Request Routing 3.0 (i have also tried with 2.5 unsuccessfully)
2. Setup 2 different IIS sites for my prod (green) and stage (blue) deployments, and confirmed they are working when directly accessing
3. Created web farm in IIS and added 2 servers

[image: server-farm]
[image: servers]

4. When I was trying to setup the URL Rewrite, I expected to see the "Route to Server Farm" action type, but I see only these options:

[image: url-rewrite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was trying to add a URL Rewrite rule on the site level instead of server level.